# Are websites supposed to know my location in Tor browser?

Tags: vpn, privacy, tor

I am using Tor, and I hear it's pretty good for privacy. But, when visiting some websites they display content specific for my real location, and the router can log my browsing history.

When I couple Tor with a VPN it works as I would expect it.

Is this the way Tor is supposed to work?

Comment: It sounds like you are leaking information, which is a big problem for systems that are configured to use TOR only some of the time. Your best bet when using TOR is to completely segregate your anonymous and non-anonymous activities on differant boxes or os instances. In this case, you are likely leaking DNS queries, which are returning local CDN results for the sites you request, and because they are leaking to your ISP, the CDN selected is one with content for your region.

Comment: By default the TOR browser has javascript and flash(?) on. Use the security slider and revisit the sites to see if they come back with you 'real' location.

Answer (score 1):

This not the way Tor is supposed to work. Tor is supposed to encrypt data before sending it through the network, and your location should appear to be the location of the exit node.

Try visiting https://check.torproject.org/ to see if you're actually connected to Tor.